# Communication between iFrames not working

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have two HTML pages in the same application hosted in Tomcat. Inside one HTML page there is an `iFrame`. I need to load the other HTML page through this iFrame.

Below I have mentioned the **controller.html**

```
   <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>postMessage Demo: Controller</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Controller Window</h1>
    <p>
      This document is on the domain: http://codepen.io
    </p>
    <p>
        <button id="send">Send Message</button>
    </p>

    <iframe id="receiver" src="http://localhost:8080/playground/receiver.html" width="400" height="200">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>

    <script>
        var btn=document.getElementById("send");
        btn.onclick = function () {
            alert("tedt")
            receiver.contentWindow.postMessage("hi", "*");
            alert("oop")
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**receiver.html**

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>postMessage Demo: Receiver</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Receiver Window</h1>
    <p>
        This document is on the domain: http://demos.matt-west.com
    </p>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <script>
        message.onload = function () {
            alert('It works!');
        var mm=document.getElementById("message");
        mm.innerHTML="asasasas";

    }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when the receiver gets the request it should display the alert 'It works' But it is not showing. Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You've got the function hooked up to a load event and not a message event, so I don't see how this relates to postMessage, but the alert fires when the page loads when I copy/paste it into an HTML file.

Comment: yes Quentin. Let me correct the receiver.html as 'message.onload'. But still the receiver.html does not show the alert.

Comment: `message.onload` is entirely wrong. What documentation are you using to learn how to use postMessage?

Comment: sorry it is window.onmessage

Comment: I didn't know that postMessage supported DOM 0 event handlers. I've only used it with the DOM 2 version. What documentation are you using to learn how to use postMessage?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: That guide doesn't use `onmessage` anywhere. It uses DOM 2 event listeners for that. Do what the tutorial says.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses an **X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP** header to disallow putting their pages in iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Almost all modern browsers will refuse to put pages with this HTTP header in an iframe. There's nothing you can do about that.